# Finding if a number is by itself in a 2d Grid

Tags: c++

So for this assignment we need to create a 2D grid and allow for inputting the Width, Height, and each element of the grid. Next we have to determine if a number is within 2 elements of another number and if it is, count it.

What I've currently tried is here:(`BUFFER` is `1` and `ROB_RANGE` is `2`)

```
int isoCount(int **arr, int x, int y)
{
  int count = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
      if(arr[i][j] != 0) {
        //This is so gross
        if( ( (arr[i + ROB_RANGE] && arr[i + BUFFER] &&
          arr[i - ROB_RANGE] && arr[i - BUFFER] ) == 0 or NULL) ) {
            if(DEBUG)
              cout << "Array: " << arr[i][j] << endl;
            count++; //Counts how many times we find a lone robot
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

However, this is not always accurate. With the provided samples I am typically ~1 count off (when an answer should be 5, it is instead 6). In the occurrence that a zero will be + 2 or - 2 seems to throw it off.

Here is a sample:

**Grid:**

```
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  +---------------
0 |1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
1 |0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
2 |0 1 0 2 0 2 0 0
3 |0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4 |1 0 0 2 0 2 0 1
```

The output should be 5 but instead I get 6.

Comment: "Next we have to determine if a number is within 2 elements of another number and if it is, count it" - please clarify. `0` is a number. `1` is a number. `2` is a number. Your sample grid contains 40 numbers that are near each other

Comment: "//This is so gross" Nah, but if it iterated 288 times it would be 2 gross.

Comment: @Fureeish Any number not zero has to be within (2) range of another not zero. If it is not within range of another not zero bidirectionally then count it.

Comment: What is "within range"? Is range only horizontal and vertical? Is it a square? In your example, which locations should be found?

Comment: @CostantinoGrana Within range basically means either -2 or +2 from the i-th element. 0 0 2 0 0 would count +1.

Comment: How come `0 0 2 0 0` counts as +1? `2` is not withing range of any non-zero number here... Is your assignment written in english? It would be helpful to see how it's clarified

Comment: I've edited the question adding coordinates to the grid. Please clarify your question by adding which numbers should be counted, otherwise no one will be able to help. In the first row how many numbers satisfy your criterion? I'd say 3 of them: all but the first one.

Comment: The assignment asks us to create a 2D Matrix of "Robots" (non zero numbers). These non zero numbers will go "mad" if they are not within 2 elements of each other (hence why `0 0 2 0 0` should count as one and `0 1 2 0 0` would not count as one). My current issue is that the program will sometimes count one extra (I don't know what this one extra is). It is my belief that it counts `0 1 2 0 0` since +2 from the 3rd element is 0.

Comment: @Aeternal, you should really try to explain the problem better. You say "It is my belief that it counts 0 1 2 0 0 since +2 from the 3rd element is 0". But that sequence is not present in your example. I'll try the last time to ask for clarification: 1) which coordinates are mad robots? In (row,col) I'd say (0,0) and (4,0). 2) "Within 2 elements" excludes diagonals?

Answer (score 0):

Since we are unable to get a clarification on the problem, I'll just try to fix some of the obvious mistakes in the OP question and then see which problem the proposed solution solves.

## 1) Mistakes in the original code

The core check is

```
if ( ( (arr[i + ROB_RANGE] && arr[i + BUFFER] && 
        arr[i - ROB_RANGE] && arr[i - BUFFER]) == 0 or NULL) ) {
```

which I strongly believe is the OP C++ version of: *if all elements within 2 positions to the left and to the right of the current element are 0 or are outside the grid*. Unfortunately this is not the case. That line of code means: *if any of the pointers to the beginning of the columns within 2 positions to the left and to the right of the current one is 0*.

Basically if you want to check if a and b are both equal to 0 the expression should be `a==0 && b==0`. The expression `(a && b) == 0` means: `( (a != 0) && (b != 0) ) == 0`, that is equivalent to `!( (a != 0) && (b != 0) )` and with the De Morgan theorem becomes: `(a == 0) || (b == 0)`.

Moreover why should you check pointers? You should be checking values, that is using two indexes. And if you check values outside the grid limits, there's no magic NULL saving you. You are reading random things. So the solution is to be sure not to go outside the image.

Anyway what I belive the OP wanted is something in the line of

```
bool c1, c2, c3, c4;
c1 = c2 = c3 = c4 = true;
if (i + ROB_RANGE < x)
    c1 = arr[i + ROB_RANGE][j]==0;
if (i + BUFFER < x)
    c2 = arr[i + BUFFER][j]==0;
if (i - ROB_RANGE >= 0)
    c3 = arr[i - ROB_RANGE][j]==0;
if (i - BUFFER >= 0)
    c4 = arr[i - BUFFER][j]==0;

if (c1 && c2 && c3 && c4) {
```

Now, what does this solve?

## 2) Problem solved by this code

Say that we have a grid of x times y numbers. Each may be identified by the couple `(i,j)` with `i` being the horizontal direction and `j` being the vertical one. Count how many non zero numbers have only zeros in the two positions to the left and in the two to the right, i.e. if there is a non zero number at `(i,j)`, the locations `(i-2,j)`, `(i-1,j)`, `(i+1,j)`, `(i+2,j)` should contain a zero or be outside the grid limits.

Is this the original problem? I don't think so, but there's no way to know...